# How to convert a string to float when the string has negative values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which was read from an xls. It has two columns with numbers that were read in as strings, these columns also have negative values in them. I am trying to convert these strings to floats but am getting an error.

I tried to replace the string, what I thought was the issue  (the '-') but I still get the error below:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

```
df2['VOL'] = df2['VOL'].str.replace('−', '-').astype(float)
```

I am expecting an output of floats without an error.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: That means you have instances where the values are just `-` instead of an actual value. can you check? I know sometimes excel put `-` as `zero`. so you need to take care of that

Comment: have you tried `pd.read_excel`?

Answer (score -1):

Replace t in the code bellow with df2['VOL'].

```
t = '−423'
t = float(t.replace('−', '-'))

print(t)
```

## output

```
-423.0
```